# Setting up Apache camel route with MDC logging enabled

Tags: spring-boot, apache-camel, spring-camel

I have the following route.

```
@Override
public void configure() throws Exception {
    onException(Exception.class).process(outboxExceptionProcessor).handled(true);
    from("seda:outbox-channel")
            .routeId("route-outbox")
            .process(outboxHeaderEnricherProcessor)
            .choice()
            .when(header("type").isEqualTo("DealInvitationEvent"))
            .multicast()
            .parallelProcessing()
            .process(invitationEventProcessor)
            .end()
            .endChoice()
            .when(header("type").isEqualTo("EnquiryAcceptedEvent"))
            .multicast()
            .parallelProcessing()
            .process(enquiryAcceptedEventProcessor)
            .end()
            .endChoice()
            .when(header("type").isEqualTo("EnquiryDeclinedEvent"))
            .multicast()
            .parallelProcessing()
            .process(enquiryDeclinedEventProcessor)
            .end()
            .endChoice()
            .otherwise()
            .process(outboxNotMatchingProcessor)
            .end()
            .process(outboxCompletionProcessor);
}
```

Following is the code to send message to this router.

```
producerTemplate.sendBodyAndHeaders(
                "seda:outbox-channel", outboxEvent.getId(), headers);
```

I have enabled the MDC logging in application.yml

```
camel:
  springboot:
    use-mdc-logging: true
    mdc-logging-keys-pattern: "*"
```

Even though whenever i log messages i don't get the value set to MDC. I have updated the logback configuration accordingly and in other places its working file but after route is getting lost

Answer (score 1):

For the benefit of others I managed to implement this as follows.

```
@Override
public void configure() throws Exception {
    onException(Exception.class).process(outboxExceptionProcessor).handled(true);
    getContext()
            .getExtension(ExtendedCamelContext.class)
            .setUnitOfWorkFactory(new CustomMDCUnitOfWorkFactory());
    from("seda:outbox-channel")
            .routeId("route-outbox")
            .process(outboxHeaderEnricherProcessor)
            .choice()
            .when(header("type").isEqualTo("DealInvitationEvent"))
            .multicast()
            .parallelProcessing()
            .process(invitationEventProcessor)
            .end()
            .endChoice()
            .when(header("type").isEqualTo("EnquiryAcceptedEvent"))
            .multicast()
            .parallelProcessing()
            .process(enquiryAcceptedEventProcessor)
            .end()
            .endChoice()
            .when(header("type").isEqualTo("EnquiryDeclinedEvent"))
            .multicast()
            .parallelProcessing()
            .process(enquiryDeclinedEventProcessor)
            .end()
            .endChoice()
            .otherwise()
            .process(outboxNotMatchingProcessor)
            .end()
            .process(outboxCompletionProcessor);
}
```

Following is the CustomMDCUnitOfWorkFactory implementation

```
public class CustomMDCUnitOfWorkFactory extends DefaultUnitOfWorkFactory {
private InflightRepository inflightRepository;
private boolean usedMDCLogging;
private String mdcLoggingKeysPattern;
private boolean allowUseOriginalMessage;
private boolean useBreadcrumb;

@Override
public UnitOfWork createUnitOfWork(Exchange exchange) {
    return new CustomMDCUnitOfWork(
            exchange,
            this.inflightRepository,
            this.mdcLoggingKeysPattern,
            this.allowUseOriginalMessage,
            this.useBreadcrumb);
}

public void afterPropertiesConfigured(CamelContext camelContext) {
    this.inflightRepository = camelContext.getInflightRepository();
    this.usedMDCLogging =
            camelContext.isUseMDCLogging() != null && camelContext.isUseMDCLogging();
    this.mdcLoggingKeysPattern = camelContext.getMDCLoggingKeysPattern();
    this.allowUseOriginalMessage =
            camelContext.isAllowUseOriginalMessage() != null
                    ? camelContext.isAllowUseOriginalMessage()
                    : false;
    this.useBreadcrumb =
            camelContext.isUseBreadcrumb() != null ? camelContext.isUseBreadcrumb() : false;
}
}
```